# Custom views inside ListView with itemViewType

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-listview

I have a ListView in my application. The adapter for this listview contains multiple item view types (around 5 till now), via which I can inflate different types of row views inside the listview.

All row views inflated inside the adapter are custom subclassed view/view group.

```
public class CustomView1 extends RelativeLayout {
    Bundle bundle;

    public CustomView1(Bundle bundle) {
        super(context);
        this.bundle = bundle;
        addSubViews(bundle.getBundleList("list"));
    }

    private void addSubViews(ArrayList<Bundle> list) {
         for(Bundle element : list) {
              //add sub views via reflection
              View view = (View) Class.forName(packageName + type).getConstructor(Bundle.class).newInstance(element);
              addView(view);
         }
    }

    //called from getView() in adapter when convertView != null
    public void onRecycle(Bundle bundle) {
         if(bundle != this.bundle) {
             this.bundle = bundle;
             removeAllViews();
             addSubViews(bundle.getBundleList("list"));
         }
    }
}
```

Bundle passed to each custom view contains layout info for that view. In this way, I can create and add any view/viewgroup inside any viewgroup. All well till now.

Now the problem comes when this code runs inside ListView. Since all the view types are created by the adapter initially, scrolling jerks a lot because the adapter keeps on creating new custom views of different itemViewType. **How to reduce those jerks in listview ? Any ideas?** In the listview, all viewTypes are different at the top 5 positions, so the adapter has to create these views and that makes the experience sluggish.

Even when the adapter recycles similar view type convertViews after 5th index, I clear the container using removeAllViews() and run this loop again because the subView bundle list of the incoming bundle from 6th position onwards might be different. So in the end, adapter is only recycling empty ViewGroups. Since the subView list can possibly contain anything (maybe one more bundle list inside any element bundle), I have to do removeAllViews() to accommodate new subview tree in the recycled convertView.

I thought of using vertical ScrollView but that would take too much memory upfront, and the number of custom views inflated is dynamic, can increase to 20.

The app is running but the scroll is so bad there is hardly any usability left, so its looking like till now I have achieved nothing by adding so much dynamic behavior also. Please suggest me ways to counter this problem.

I am suspecting that the use of setLayoutParams inside CustomView classes may be stopping the scroll because I set the width/height of all views after they are created.

**Update #1** getView() code using ViewHolder pattern

```
ViewHolder holder; 
if(convertView == null) { 
  holder = new ViewHolder(); 
  holder.customView1 = new CustomView1(bundle);
  convertView = holder.customView1; 
  convertView.setTag(holder); 
} else { 
  holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag(); 
} 
holder.customView1.onRecycle(bundle);
```

Answer (score 0):

`ListView` has excellent support for different `View` types. Just make sure to use view holder pattern to avoid jerky scrolling and then `override` `getViewTypeCount()` and `getItemViewType()`.

More detail http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296

Comment: I am using all these methods, viewHolder also. I found that obvious to not point out. The problem is that different item view types are created at top positions, so the adapter creates all these custom views resulting in scroll lag. I even tried pre-inflating the custom views and assigning it to converView before scrolling starts.

Comment: If you are calling `onRecycle()` method from `getView()` then whats the point of view holder pattern? It will result in worst user experience.

Comment: Please try to understand the intent of view holder pattern. It is used to avoid View inflation as well as to avoid `findViewById` call. But adding and removing views causes full layout measurement to happen which is even worse IMHO in this case.

Comment: and above all you are using reflection to inflate view, reflection itself is slower.

Comment: I know but I dont have any other option. These customViews can possibly contain anything. I am trying to make these row views generic, so that can iteratively add any viewgroup inside them which can further contain more views. Keeping that requirement in mind, I have made all this. If i dont do removeAllViews() then the previous view hierarchy attached would stick but that should not happen. Using this, I am showing viewpager inside listviews, pager inside pager, linearlayout inside pager etc, and all of this goes inside the parent listview.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54741/discussion-between-m-wajeeh-and-hbansal).

Comment: Everything I am using is out of practice I am well aware, but the dynamic requirements have forced us to make it like that. :( I cannot possibly know what our API can add inside the listview, it can be a pager with LinearLayout, or a pager with more pager inside in the same  listview. So to match all that and to make it generic, I have used what I have used.